# How to create html files with incoming data from a server in Android?

Tags: android

I want to know if it is possible to create a html file as a background process while showing a temporary html file on screen. After downloading necessary files from server and creating/generating the new html file, i want to know how to put that newly created file into view? I am currently working on creating a html file but couldn't find a way to do it.

To be more clear, what I am trying to make is an app which will communicate with a server and get some media objects from it. (e.g text,rss feed, movies, images ..) That app will be the client side of server. It will serve as a digital signage application. However i couldn't figure out how to represent layouts with android. I don't know if it is possible to make it but what is on my mind is making a html file for each layout and show it through WebView.

Any idea or suggestion will be so helpful.

Comment: but what about the layouts that will come after creating first HTML. Is there a way to create new HTML files dynamically?

Comment: and also about making html files. what will be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why not use progressbar to show loading progress

Comment: i can currently create html file with some javascript on it but still couldnt find a way to switch between different media's/layouts etc. using progressbar just make it much more user friendly an i ll go on that issue after i can make a working app for more than one media.

Comment: I'd get the HTML files from server. But in case I have data coming from server and have to make an html file locally, I'd treat it as an XML file and create an XML file with data from server and then feed it to the WebView.

Comment: currently i am succesfully creating the html file to load it onto webview. But thanks for advice I ll try it and see if it has more benefits than creating a html with some templates.